# PHP If Statement Issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I am working on something, but with my if statements, it will say "test" no matter what, not following the other if statements.  Help please, heres my code:

```
<?php
$userr = $_POST['user'];
$user = ucwords($userr);
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if ($submit) 
{
    if ($userr && $pass) 
    {
        if ($user == "Admin" && $pass == "password") 
        {
            echo "Logged in";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Fill in all fields";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Submit!";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "test";
}
?>
```

Comment: a random guess: is $submit always evaluated to false?

Comment: What would happen when the user `false` would register? or `000000`? or `null`?

Comment: as @AndreasHenning said, theres nothing that would set $submit to true. wild guess, change it to $_POST['submit'] ?

Comment: I am makign this for a friend, doesn't need to really be regulated.

Comment: Use *ALWAYS* strict comparisons `===` with passwords!!

Comment: @AndreasHenning: http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/210/119/+_2acc5a8841f8752904d37f90a8014829.png. The point is it would break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are initializing your `$submit`?

By a look at your code, I think you need:

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely because `$submit` always evaluates to `false`.

Make sure that `$submit` is defined and is what you expect it to be.

Also, if `$user == 'false'` your script will break without warning.